# WSO2 Developer Studio Registry Browser Perspective Exception

Tags: wso2

I am geting an exception in the eclipse logs hen I try to access my registry entries in the Registry Browser perspective (and when I try to import registry entries into a registry project).

the exception is as follows: (any assistance would be much appreciated)

```
!MESSAGE java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    org.apache.abdera.parser.stax.FOMParser
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.apache.abdera.parser.stax.FOMParser
at org.apache.abdera.util.Discover.locate(Discover.java:56)
at org.apache.abdera.util.Discover.locate(Discover.java:23)
at org.apache.abdera.util.AbderaConfiguration.newParserInstance(AbderaConfiguration.java:320)
at org.apache.abdera.Abdera.newParser(Abdera.java:224)
at org.apache.abdera.Abdera.getParser(Abdera.java:156)
at org.apache.abdera.protocol.client.AbstractClientResponse.<init>(AbstractClientResponse.java:57)
at org.apache.abdera.protocol.client.CommonsResponse.<init>(CommonsResponse.java:44)
at org.apache.abdera.protocol.client.AbderaClient.execute(AbderaClient.java:796)
at org.apache.abdera.protocol.client.AbderaClient.get(AbderaClient.java:235)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.app.RemoteRegistry.get(RemoteRegistry.java:162)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.base.core.Registry.get(Registry.java:825)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.manager.remote.views.ResourceInfoViewer.updateGeneralInfo(ResourceInfoViewer.java:269)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.manager.remote.views.ResourceInfoViewer.updateInfo(ResourceInfoViewer.java:224)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.manager.remote.views.ResourceInfoViewer.updateMe(ResourceInfoViewer.java:334)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.manager.remote.views.RegistryBrowserView$48.widgetSelected(RegistryBrowserView.java:2391)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1458)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1481)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1466)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1271)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3980)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:4869)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5239)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDownSuper(Widget.java:1093)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.mouseDownSuper(Tree.java:2052)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDown(Widget.java:1085)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseDown(Control.java:2538)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.mouseDown(Tree.java:2007)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5493)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowSendEvent(Widget.java:2102)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowSendEvent(Shell.java:2284)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5557)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationSendEvent(Display.java:5002)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5151)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.sendEvent(NSApplication.java:128)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3616)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.abdera.parser.stax.FOMParser
at org.apache.abdera.util.Discover.getClass(Discover.java:235)
at org.apache.abdera.util.Discover.load(Discover.java:210)
at org.apache.abdera.util.Discover.locate(Discover.java:47)
... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.abdera.parser.stax.FOMParser
at  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
at org.apache.abdera.util.Discover.getClass(Discover.java:231)
... 66 more
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information regarding the issue such as the Developer Studio version you are using, Carbon Server type and version you are using and your O/S platform...?

Comment: Hi, yes. Apologies, it was a little silly of me to leave all that information out!. I am using Dev studio 2.1 as an eclipse plugin (I cannot get the full eclipse dev studio download to even run unfortunately). Eclipse is running on osx mountain lion (64bit) and the server I am connecting to is a remote wso2ESB server running esb 4.5 on ubuntu 12.04 server 64bit.